# how to take backup of database into local machine through network connection?

Tags: sql-server, backup

My database Name: Vallett, PCName:SUPPORT2, Shared folder Name=Backup

I want to take backup of database base in sql server connected through netework.
I am connecting database of sql through a network connection, I try to take backup of that in my local PC, but I am not getting backup of that database in my local PC.
I created one shared folder in my local pc then I tried to execute this query in sql server:

```
BACKUP DATABASE Vallett
  TO DISK = '\\SUPPORT2\Backup\Vallett.BAK'
```

but following error is shown

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot open backup device '\\SUPPORT2\Backup\Vallett.BAK'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Is there any way to take a backup to local machine from the network connected database.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/51788/how-to-backup-sql-databases-to-a-network-share/

Comment: while i am giving passoword here(SQL SERVER(MSSQLSERVER)) showing error:the account name is invalied ,or does not exist or the password is invalied for the account name is specified

Comment: @user2674855 There are some methods available on the internet but, those are not working in all system. But, It doesn't mean that you cannot do that. I have to chose different way. This cannot be done directly.